# Parsing XML in Android (XmlPullParserException)

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm currently learning Android programming and when I'm trying to parse the XML, I get this error below (The program runs fine but it only parse the first XML link):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public class RSSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * List of feeds that has been fetched.
 */
public static ArrayList<RSSFeed> Feeds;

/**
 * Button for Seattle Times
 */
private Button mSeattleBtn;

/**
 * Button for ESPN
 */
private Button mESPNBtn;

/**
 * The layout contains the loading image
 */
private RelativeLayout mProgress;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss);

    Feeds = new ArrayList<>();
    mProgress = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSeattleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seattle_times);
    mSeattleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DownloadXML().execute("http://www.seattletimes.com/feed/",
                    "http://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/feed/",
                    "http://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/feed/");
        }
    });

    mESPNBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.espn_btn);
    mESPNBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DownloadXML().execute("http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news",
                    "http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/nfl/news",
                    "http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/nba/news");
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Async task to fetch the XML from the internet
 */
private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    /**
     * The name of the current class, used for Log (debugging)
     */
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadXML";

    /**
     * The content of the xml that has been fetched from the internet
     */
    private String xmlContent;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        xmlContent = "";
        mSeattleBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mESPNBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // set the xml contents to xmlContent
        //xmlContent = getXMLContent(params[0]);
        for (String s: params) {
            xmlContent += getXMLContent(s);
        }

        // This will return the xmlContent to the onPostExecute method.
        return xmlContent;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the actual downloading process of the RSS
     * file here.
     *
     * @param path the url path of the rss feed.
     * @return the completed download xml file (converted to String)
     */
    private String getXMLContent(String path) {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            // Open the connection
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int charToRead;
            // reading 1000 bytes at a time.
            char[] input = new char[1000];

            // Keep reading the file until there's no more bytes(chars) left to read
            while(true) {
                charToRead = inputStreamReader.read(input);
                if(charToRead <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                temp.append(String.copyValueOf(input, 0, charToRead));
            }

            return temp.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        RSSFeed curFeed = null;
        boolean inItem = false;
        String value = "";

        try {
            // Instantiate XmlPullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            // specify that the code will be supported by XML namespaces
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(result));
            int event = parser.getEventType();

            // Parse the XML content
            while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tag = parser.getName();

                // Only parse with the starting and ending tag of "item"
                // and every tags inside it, ignore other tags.
                switch(event) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        // if the begin tag is item which mean
                        // we can begin to to fetch the xml tags we want into our application
                        if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            inItem = true;
                            curFeed = new RSSFeed();
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        value = parser.getText();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        /*
                            while reach the end tag of the current tag
                            if the end tag is title then set it to the current feed title,
                            if the end tag is link then set it to the current feed link,
                            if the end tag is pubdate then set it to the current feed pubdate,
                            if the end tag is item we know that there's no more contents to add
                            to the current feed so we move on to parse another feed.
                         */
                        if(inItem){
                            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                                curFeed.setTitle(value);
                            } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                                curFeed.setLink(value);
                            } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")) {
                                curFeed.setDate(value);
                            } else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                                Feeds.add(curFeed);
                                inItem = false;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:

                }

                event = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        findViewById(R.id.loading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(RSSActivity.this, FeedListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
}
```

Since I'm new to all these, could someone please explain to me what's going on here? Looks like the error came from the parser.

EDIT: if I pass only one parameter to the Asynctask.execute() then everything run fine.

**SOLUTION:**

The only solution now is to process each URL serially as replied by **nikhil.thakkar**

> Then i would suggest you to process each url serially..

Comment: I think there is problem with your xml. Can you please paste the xml as well.

Comment: The links to the xml are in the anonymous classes of setOnClickListener()

Comment: Can you print the temp variable and paste the contents here in string.

Comment: the contents are too long to be able to paste here, but it looks like it prints out XML contents.

Comment: There is something wrong with the string since the logcat says so.

Comment: If I pass only one argument to the AsyncTask.execute() method, it doesn't me any error.  If I pass more than 1 it gives me the error but it parses the first argument just fine. uhmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93640/discussion-between-nikhil-thakkar-and-ln206).

Answer (score 1):

Please check in onPostExecute method.You are accessing token which is not exist in XML file.

Comment: Hi, I just doubled check the XML links, each RSS feed start with the `item` tag, and there's `link`, `title`, `pubdate` tags in each `item` tag. If that was you meant, or else I still don't understand what you just said, sorry.